# Nullreference Exception TemplateRedirectionPage.ComputeRedirectionVirtualPath

Tags: 2013

Another developer left abruptly recently and his project for which he was the only developer was dropped into my lap. I pull down the solution and it builds. When I try to debug it, I get some internal-to-SharePoint exceptions in different places. On the `default.aspx` page, I get:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>       Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ComputeRedirectionVirtualPath(TemplateRedirectionPage basePage) +310
>       Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CmsVirtualPathProvider.CombineVirtualPaths(String basePath, String relativePath) +185
>   System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.CombineVirtualPaths(VirtualPath basePath, VirtualPath relativePath) +59 
>   System.Web.UI.DependencyParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) +12517215 
>   System.Web.UI.PageDependencyParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive) +29

I am wondering if I need to setup the site collection with a different site template? I used `Blank Site` but I think he is using a `Team Site` with `Publishing Features`. Could that cause what I am seeing here?

This is a snippet from the page throwing the error:

```
        <%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingIsFurlPage,PublishingPageImage,PublishingPageContent,SummaryLinks,ArticleByLine,ArticleStartDate,PublishingImageCaption,HeaderStyleDefinitions,SeoBrowserTitle,SeoMetaDescription,SeoKeywords,RobotsNoIndex"><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">24</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingIsFurlPage msdt:dt="string">0</mso:PublishingIsFurlPage>...
```

Any ideas? Should I drop the site collection and recreate as a Team Site with Publishing?

**PS:** I am not a seasoned SP Dev.